# window.open() isn't opening with the height I pass to it

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I'm trying to set `height=200` and `width=200` on a window, but all I get is the standard page size. I've tried other height and width sizes but it keeps opening the same size.

**Here's the code:**

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(
    Page.GetType(), 
    "cadastrarProduto", 
    "window.open('CadastroProduto.aspx','height=200, width=200',false)", 
    true);
```

cadastrarProduto is the string key I chose.
CadastroProduto.aspx is the page I'm redirecting with the script.

I'm trying to do this on asp.net, if there is better way to PopUp a window I would like to know.

Comment: You need to pass a blank parameter like this: `window.open('CadastroProduto.aspx','','height=100, width=100',false)`

Comment: Ahhh verdade, obrigado!!

Comment: `window.open` is a bad idea. Many browsers, virus scanners and popup blockers block it. Better use a Modal.

Answer (score 1):

> try it it will work

```
Response.Write("<script> window.open('" + "CadastroProduto.aspx" +
 "','_blank','toolbar = yes, width = 100, height = 100'); </script>");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
window.open(URL, name, specs, replace)
```

name is optional. It can be empty.
So, have a blank parameter and then add height value.

```
window.open('CadastroProduto.aspx',' ','height=100, width=100',false)
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing the name parameter (2nd - it's optional, but that means you can pass an empty value, not just skip it).
Quoting https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp below:

> Optional. Specifies the target attribute or the name of the window.
>   The following values are supported:
>
> ```
> _blank - URL is loaded into a new window. This is default
> _parent - URL is loaded into the parent frame
> _self - URL replaces the current page
> _top - URL replaces any framesets that may be loaded
> name - The name of the window (Note: the name does not specify the title of the new window)
> ```